# Error while reading Excel file in SOAPUI using Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to read an Excel file, inside SOAPUi (Free version) using Groovy.

Code :

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;

def path = "D:\\Automation\\Testdata\\testdata.xlsx"
def inputStream = new FileInputStream(path)
def wb=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)
def workSheet=wb.getSheet("sheet1")
def rows=workSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()
long.info rows
```

Error :

```
java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception
```

I am new to SOAPUI and Groovy, but I have a decent knowledge on java. Couldnt find a proper solution for this.

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: def wb=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)

Comment: Have you tried with `def inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path))`? Otherwise, add full stacktrace.

Comment: If the exception is thrown at `XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream)` a probably cause is an `OutOfMemory`, you can try increasing the heap. However this is only a guess due to lack of information. Note that `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` doesn't help to much here... copy the full stacktrace to see what is really happening `:)`.